# Parent class called before child

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython

I am working on creating a child class that inherits from [PySndfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysndfile/0.2.1) that would contain extra functions related to the PySndfile class.

However, when initialising the child class with a keyword argument not intended for the PySndfile class, it appears that arguments are sent straight to the parent class, bypassing the child's **init** altogether (ie the print statment isn't called, the argument isn't popped from kwargs and the traceback doesn't refer to the child class at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.

ClassProblem.py:

```
from pysndfile import PySndfile

class AudioFile(PySndfile):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode, rms="123"):
        print 'AudioFile init called'
        self.rms = rms
        super(AudioFile, self).__cinit__(
                self, 
                filename, 
                mode=mode, 
                format=None,
                channels=None, 
                samplerate=None
                )

aa = AudioFile(
    "/path/to/audio/file.wav",
    'r',
    rms="456",
    )
```

Error produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ClassProblem.py", line 18, in <module>
    rms="456",
  File "_pysndfile.pyx", line 564, in _pysndfile.PySndfile.__cinit__ (_pysndfile.cpp:3308)
TypeError: __cinit__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rms'
```

Comment: Just remove `self` parameter when calling super method. You're already passing this with super function.

Comment: Ok I tried this and have removed it but this doesn't seem to have changed anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by posting this question to the [/r/learnpython sub-reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/30tbtf/parent_class_called_before_the_child_class/)

The user yes_or_gnome provides a great explanation as to why I needed to override the __new__ class method as well as the __init__ method and has provided example code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you'll have to override `__new__`, according to the [cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/special_methods.html#initialisation-methods-cinit-and-init):

> If you anticipate subclassing your extension type in Python, you may find it useful to give the **cinit**() method * and ** arguments so that it can accept and ignore extra arguments. Otherwise, any Python subclass which has an **init**() with a different signature will have to override **new**() [1] as well as **init**(), which the writer of a Python class wouldn’t expect to have to do.

Answer (score 0):

PySndfile appears to be a Cython library. I don't know anything at all about Cython, but it appears from the traceback that it uses `__cinit__` rather than `__init__`. You should probably override that method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively passing `**kwargs` up to the PySndfile constructor but it doesn't know what to do with the `rms` argument which is specific to your class. I don't have PySndfile locally but after a quick look online, I see the pyx constructor looks like this:

```
def __cinit__(self, filename, mode='r', int format=0,
             int channels=0, int samplerate=0):
```

This is not an `*args, **kwargs` function, able to take any arguments, rather it has a fixed signature. I would suggest updating your class with a similar constructor to which you can add the arguments specific to your class:

```
def __init__(self, filename, mode='r', rms=0, format=0,
             channels=0, samplerate=0):
```

Then pass all the arguments to the super constructor (except rms, which it does not understand).

Comment: Actually, what OP did would perfectly work for standard classes, since he explicitly removes the additional `rms` argument before calling `super().__init__`. Using `*args` and `**kwargs` in this way is perfectly acceptable (and necessitates less maintenance if arguments change in the parent).